# Java FX Scene Builder on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, javafx

I installed JavaFX Scene Builder and it don't show on preferences on my Eclipce Jboss Edition ! ! I can not even create a new  FXML file ! I did The JavaFX librairie add !

Comment: Install the [e(fx)clipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/efxclipse)

Comment: i did it ! i forget to mention that before ! nothing changed same here

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect this.